# Проверка введенных данных QTableWidget

Tags: c++, qt

Доброго времени суток коллеги. Есть задача используя `QTableWidget` проверять введенные пользователем данные в ячейки с помощью нехитрой конструкции.

`connect(ui->tableWidget,SIGNAL(cellChanged(int,int)),this,SLOT(test_slot1(int,int)));`

Где слот `test_slot1` получает позицию ячейки с которой в данный момент работает пользователь. Проблема в том что данная конструкция работает только после завершения редактирования строки.

Есть аналог в классе `QLineEdit`, который имеет сигнал `textChanged`, это именно то что мне нужно, НО аналога для `QTableWidget` я не нашел.

Возможно необходимо переопределить сигнал другого класса или использовать `QEvent` дайте пинок в нужном направлении.

Comment: Во-первых, у Вас явно не `QWidget`, а `QTableWidget`, почему в заголовке и в вопросе это не отражено, чтобы запутать тех, кто пытается Вам помочь? Во-вторых, перед тем, как задавать вопрос, неплохо хотя бы взглянуть на документацию по классу, с которым возникли проблемы. В нём есть сигнал `currentCellChanged`, который, судя по описанию, должен помочь.

Answer (score 2):

В зависимости от типа редактируемых данных создаваемый редактор может быть очень разным, в том числе, не быть QLineEdit. Поэтому трудно ожидать нужного вам сигнала в классе таблицы, иначе пришлось бы создать аналоги сигналов для всех возможных редакторов.

Вероятно, то тебе нужно:

1. Создать собственную реализацию QItemDelegate. (унаследоваться от этого класса)
2. Перекрыть метод creteEditor. Можно сперва вызвать QItemDelegate::createEditor, и если был создан QLineEdit, то подключиться к его сигналам.
3. установить свой делегат с помощью метода setItemDelegate